# Is there a python function that inside a loops, after that it reach the last index of a list, it will go again to first index, and loops restart?

Tags: python, list, iterator

I know that is a strange question about algorithm, but it's a question that is in my mind for a few days. See the code below, i have a list of days from 1 to 31, and i want to do a loop to print them, and when n (i use n for index of the list ( is just an example)) is equal to the last index, after that, it will be reset to 0, and loops will restart again.

I tryed to do that by writing this code, but i would ask you if there is a built-in function or other less long or something that is really dedicated to doing this.

Think for example to a game, in this imaginary game there are 4 players, so there are 4 turns, and the list, that is [0, 1, 2, 3], will be iterated continuosly, after that loops arrives to 3, it will go back to 0.

Is there a way to do that (a specific way)?

```
from time import sleep


days = [day for day in range(1, 32)]

while True:
    for n in range(0, 31):
        print(days[n])
        sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Not in general, since iterators don't have any built-in way to reset them.

Comment: BTW, you're always skipping day 1 and 31 of the month.

Comment: @Peymanmohsenikiasari How is that related? There's no recursion here, just wrapping around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import cycle

for item in cycle([0, 1, 2, 3]):
    print(item)
```

out:

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
...
```

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you very much! I was looking for just that